# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Agent to Fellow

Tags: java, anylogic

In my model, various practitioners go to see patients multiple times in one visit. I am trying to ensure the same fellow is used to see a patient over multiple visits after being seized and released multiple times. I continue to receive this Type mismatch. Type Patient is the agent being pushed through the model and type Fellow belongs to a resource pool of 3 fellows.

[image: ResourcePool params]
[image: Main code]
[image: Error]

Comment: Inside which agent is this resourcePool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes

1. Your screenshot is of the resource pool named Fellows - yet you market the Unit type as `Patient` - it should be `Fellow` if you want the resource pool to contain agents of type `Fellow` and have patients flow through the process flow and seize Fellows

[image]

2. In the `on seize` code you have two local variables you can use

[image]

Unit  - is the Fellow, the resource unit from this pool
agent - the agent that seized the unit (can be literally anything) so you need to cast it to what you think it is going to be.. AnyLogic cant do it or you as it has no idea what agent type will seize it

[image]

3. Your custom resource choice will then also change

We again need to cast the agent to a `Patient` again

[image]

---

NB - remember that this logic will throw a cast class exception error if any other agent than a Patient seizes a fellow.

Answer (score -1):

You must ensure that the variable `fellow` in your `Patient` agent type is of type `Fellow`.

You try to store the `Fellow` in the `Patient.fellow` variable but that variable is not of type `Fellow`, causing the problem.